# {"status":{"error":"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"}}

Tags: php, mysql, slim

```
$app->get('/view/appointment/:databaseID/:userID/:appointmentID', function($databaseID, $userID, $appointmentID) use($app) {

    $params['databaseID'] = $databaseID; //$request->getAttribute('databaseID');
    $id = $userID; //$request->getAttribute('userID');    
    $date = $appointmentID; //$request->getAttribute('appointmentID');

    $sql = "SELECT imapt_date, imapt_start_time, imapt_end_time, imapt_patient_id, imapt_procedure
        from im_ap_timetable inner join im_practioner on
        im_ap_timetable.impract_id=im_practioner.impract_id inner join  
        im_users_cd on im_practioner.user_id=im_users_cd.user_id
        where im_users_cd.user_id = :id and im_ap_timetable.imapt_date = :date";

    try {
        $db = getDB($params['databaseID']);
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query = compact('id');
        $stmt->execute($query);

        $patient = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $status = array('success' => '200');

        echo json_encode(compact('patient','status'));

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $status = array('error' => $e->getMessage());

        echo json_encode(compact('status'));

    }

});
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: I was testing /view/appointment/clientDemo/25/2016-01-14 on postman. However, I'm getting {"status":{"error":"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"}} . By right system should reply with json format with the list of values I want

Answer (score 1):

You have two placeholders: `:id` and `:date`.

But you bind only one - `:id`.

You need to bind `:date` too. In your case it is:

```
$query = compact('id', 'date');
```

Comment: Thanks. Im still new in this

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `bindParam` method to bind the parameters to your SQL query.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

You may also pass them into an array within your `execute` method.

`$stmt->execute($query, [':id' => $id, ':date' => $date]);`